# chart.js - How draw x and y axes lines on the left and bottom

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

I use chart.js v2 library to draw a chart.
I tried to set a zero line but it's not working.
I need to draw two lines like on the screenshot below. Is it possible to draw with some cinfiguration options?
[image]

```js
var options = {
  type: 'scatter',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: [{
          x: 20,
          y: 1
        },
        {
          x: 21,
          y: 1.1
        },
        {
          x: 23,
          y: 1.4
        },
      ],
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: false,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 1,
          max: 2,
          display: false,
        },
        gridLines: {
          color: 'transparent',
          display: true,
          zeroLineColor: 'red'
        },
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 1,
          max: 99,
        },
        gridLines: {
          color: 'transparent',
          display: true,
          zeroLineColor: 'red'
        },
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
    <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```

Here is a fiddle with code:
https://jsfiddle.net/c4wotrx1/4/

Comment: The screenshot + jsfiddle show the same result. Please add more details about what's not working.

Comment: @0stone0 at the fiddle there is no lines as on the screenshot, I need them

Comment: zeroLine wont work since you set your min to be 1 so there is no 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to enable the `gridLines` on both `xAxes` and `yAxes`, but disable the `drawOnchartArea`:

```json
xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 1,
          max: 99,
        },
        gridLines: {
          color: 'red',
          display: true,
          drawBorder: true,
          drawOnChartArea: false
        },
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
           color: 'red',
            display: true,
            drawBorder: true,
            drawOnChartArea: false
        }
     }]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try below, you need to keep the lines but hide them in the chart area.

This you can do by drawOnChartArea: false, see this [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.6.0/axes/styling.html?h=gridlines)

```
gridLines: {
        drawBorder:true,
      drawOnChartArea: false,
      color: 'red',
      display: true,
      zeroLineColor: 'red'
    },
```

hope this helps.